# rails, rest, render different action with responds to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Maybe my logic is not restful or know if this is how you would do it but this is what I am trying to do.

I'm getting a category inside a category controller and then once I get that category I want to return to an index page in a different controller but keep that @category and the Category.busineses.

Before rest I would have just done this:

render :controller => "businesses"

and it would have rendered the view of the index action in that controller.

now in my respond_to block I have this

```
   format.html {redirect_to(business_path)} # index.html.erb
   format.xml  { render :xml => @businesses }
```

but of course with a render it looses the instance variable and starts with a new action.

So what I want to do is render the action instead of redirecting to that action.
is this possible?

Should i just replace the respond_to with render :controller => ?

Comment: Sam, you mean `render :action => "foo"`? Your explanation is very confusing.

Comment: +1 to confusing q ... :P

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing part but rest is a whole new paradigm for me and I'm not sure where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do (if I understand it correctly) would be best achieved using nested resources. If there are businesses separated into categories, and you want to display a listing of all businesses in a specific category, you could set up your application like this:

**Models**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Routes**

```
map.resouces :businesses

map.resources :categories do |categories|
  categories.resources :businesses
end
```

**Controller**

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id]
    conds = params[:category_id] ? { :category_id => params[:category_id] } : nil
    @businesses = Business.all(:conditions => conds)
  end
end
```

Then simply access the list of a category's businesses like this: `/category/1/businesses`

Comment: so what about if I just want to get the index action with a full list of businesses not by categories. check for params[:category_id] ?

Comment: @Sam - Check out my edit for an example of how to use the same action for both `/businesses` and for `/category/1/businesses`.

Comment: Thanks really great. BTW - What do you think is the best resource for learning rest on rails?

Comment: The guide on the official site is quite good if you haven't seen it already: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html There are also several good Railscasts in the routing category including nested routing and custom REST actions: http://railscasts.com/tags/14

Comment: def index is missing a closing parenthesis on params[:category_id]

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% clear of what you are trying to do, but you have several options for presentation in a RESTful app.

You can pass a parameters in a redirect. In this case we pass the category id as a parameter in the HTTP GET. The page on the end of the redirect can then handle this appropriately:

```
format.html {redirect_to( business_path(:category_id => @category.id) }
```

You can also render the view of a specified action or template. In this case we render the view defined in "{current_controller}/business.html.erb":

```
format.html { render :action => "business" }
```

Comment: format.html { render :action => "index" } was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You cann't use redirect_to if you want instance variable as it is use render as follows.

```
format.html { render :controller=> 'buisness'  ,:action => "index" }
```

OR JUSt

```
format.html { render :controller=> 'buisness'}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. I think you answered just after Toby otherwise I would have given you the check instead of a vote

Comment: it's ok Sam. but remember format.html { render :action => "business" }
as in Toby's Answer must be format.html { render :controller => "business" } otherwise it will look for the page at the categories/buisness.html.erb. I know it's just typo or may be in hurry but take a look at it. else is fine.